# mod rewrite with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a htaccess file with mod rewrite but no luck.

The original url is

```
http://www.bpages.com/beta/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=1770&sobi2Id=94872&Itemid=
```

I want the new url should be

```
http://www.bpages.com/beta/abc/xyz
```

`catid=1770` refers to `abc`,
`sobi2Id=94872` refers to `xyz`,
`beta` is a sub directory

Is it possible.Please suggest the best possible way.

Thanks in advance,

Prithvi

Comment: How is the mapping catid->abz and sobi2Id->xyz defined?

Comment: Eduardo has a good point, nowhere in your URL do you reference any mapping for 'abc' and 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want, though I haven't tested it. Also... the Itemid part is empty. Was that just a mistake, or is it supposed to be empty?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^beta/([^/]+)/(.+)$ beta/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=$1&sobi2Id=$2&Itemid= [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then these rules should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=([^&]+)&sobi2Id=([^&]+)& [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(beta/.*)$ /$1/%1/%2? [L,R,NC]
```